# Groovy: Delete/Add Xml nodes

Tags: xml, groovy

It is an extension of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013380/xslt-working-with-for-each-loop/).
If I get input xml like this

```
<ClientInformation>
        <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
        <LastName>Jobs</LastName>
        <MiddleName/>
        <DateOfBirth>09/18/2013</DateOfBirth>
        <RoleTypeCT>OWN</RoleTypeCT>
        <RoleTypeCT>IBE</RoleTypeCT>        
        <RoleTypeCT>Insured</RoleTypeCT>
</ClientInformation>
```

Output Xml should be

```
<ClientInformation>
            <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
            <LastName>Jobs</LastName>
            <MiddleName/>
            <DateOfBirth>09/18/2013</DateOfBirth>
            <RoleTypeCT>OWN</RoleTypeCT>
    </ClientInformation>
<ClientInformation>
            <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
            <LastName>Jobs</LastName>
            <MiddleName/>
            <DateOfBirth>09/18/2013</DateOfBirth>
            <RoleTypeCT>IBE</RoleTypeCT>        
    </ClientInformation>
<ClientInformation>
            <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
            <LastName>Jobs</LastName>
            <MiddleName/>
            <DateOfBirth>09/18/2013</DateOfBirth>   
            <RoleTypeCT>Insured</RoleTypeCT>
    </ClientInformation>
```

**Groovy Code**

```
if(it.name()=="ClientInformation") {
  println it.RoleTypeCT.size() //prints 3 on console

}
```

I am thinking of following steps:

1. Assign `it` to a local variable. `def clientInfo = it`
2. Delete all the `RoleTypeCT` nodes from `clientInfo`. Tried `clientInfo.RoleTypeCT.replaceNode{}` but it gave me error.
3. For each RoleTypeCT in original `it`, add `RoleTypeCT` to `clientInfo`. Something like

   `it.RoleTypeCT.each {
     def roleType = it
     clientInfo.appendNode(roleType)
    }`

If this approach is ok then how would delete all `RoleTypeCT` nodes at the first place?

Comment: Again, that is not valid xml output...  You mean you want to output 3 separate documents?  Why not do the XSLT in your previous question to generate the 3 nodes wrapped in a `<SavedData>` node, then use `XmlSlurper` to output each node as a separate document (as in my last comment on the accepted answer)?

Comment: Don't worry about that. Each output will go to XSLT for transformation and then it will be added to a parent xml based on it's PK. There are multiple transformation happening with multiple Xmls.

Comment: Do you know how would I delete all `RoleTypeCT` node from xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you remove all the `RoleTypeCT` nodes, however I still have concerns you're walking the wrong path (see comment to question)

```
import groovy.xml.*

def client = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )

client.RoleTypeCT*.replaceNode {}

println XmlUtil.serialize( client )
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally I implemented it as you suggested. :)